# Reading a excel CSV file

Tags: import, csv-format

I have a CSV file with exactly the following data:

```
Fecha,"Último","Apertura","Máximo","Mínimo","Vol.","% var."
01.05.2020,"51,62","51,82","52,21","50,14","161,14K","-2,92%"
30.04.2020,"53,17","51,78","53,83","51,26","185,33K","0,47%"
29.04.2020,"52,92","51,00","54,55","50,88","249,92K","5,27%"
```

How can I import the file correctly? `Import[name,"CVS"]` does not recognize the different data fields.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `Import[name,"CSV"]`.

Comment: This is explained in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html . Voting to close.

Comment: The documentation is insuficient, the "%" and the use of  3 formats date number and % it is not explained. the use of th "," is complicated too... It should be simple but it is not

Comment: @roble_t Please, reformulate your question. It is not clear what do you consider correct importing.

Comment: Import[file_name, "Data"] or Import[file_name,"CSV"] does not work.

Comment: d2=Import[file_name,"Data"] and  Do[Do[d2[[i]][[j]]=Interpreter["Number",NumberPoint->","][d2[[i]][[j]]],{j,2,3}],{i,1,Length[d2]}];
Do[Interpreter["StructuredDate",DateFormat->{"Day",".","Month",".","Year"}][d2[[ii]][[1]]]]>0,
{AppendTo[pp,{Interpreter["StructuredDate",DateFormat->{"Day",".","Month",".","Year"}][d2[[ii]][[1]]],d2[[ii]][[2]]}],contd=contd+1}],{ii,Length[d2],1,-1}];   works but should be any more simple

Comment: Also note that "CSV" is not an Excel data format, but a standard format for storing tabulated data in text format (by seperating entries with commas). By default MS Office will open CSV files with Excel, and as a result CSV files will show up on most windows machines with an Excel logo next to it, but its is not an Excel data format.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not well formatted for a simple "one line" Import. The best you can manage with focus on simplicity is:

```
Import[filename,"CSV","DateStringFormat"->{"Day",".","Month",".","Year"},"NumberPoint"->","]
```

Assuming you want to replace the numbers containing K with the value times 1000 and the numbers containing % with the value divided by 100, then I suggest using Dataset with the following line of code:

```
Import[filename,"Dataset",HeaderLines->1,"DateStringFormat"->{"Day",".","Month",".","Year"},"NumberPoint"->","][
All,{
"Vol."->(ToExpression[StringReplace[#,{","->".","K"->"*1000"}]]&),
"% var."->(ToExpression[StringReplace[#,{","->".","%"->"/100"}]]&)
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, however the problem is how to import the last element with the %    the import show 0,64% with "," and it is an string not a number

Comment: I improved the solution, but you seriously need to specify what you expect as the correct output. I am just guessing this is what you want.